# Cannot curl to the docker container

Tags: docker, curl

I build the docker image

```
...
ENV PORT=8080
ENV ADDRESS=0.0.0.0

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["node", "/usr/app/src"]
```

I can run it by docker run

```
[HttpFastifyServer]: Initializing server on address 0.0.0.0:8080
[HttpFastifyServer]: └── (empty root node)
    ├── / (POST)
    │   └── / (POST)
    └── * (OPTIONS)

[Process]: Process initialized
```

But I cannot curl it.

```
$ curl -X POST http://0.0.0.0:8080/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 8080: Connection rejected
$ curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8080: Connection rejected
$ curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection rejected
```

I don't see any ip address

```
$ docker inspect myImage:1.0.0  | grep "IPAddress"
$
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you forward that port?

Comment: How exactly are you running the container; what is the `docker run` command or `docker-compose.yml` you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expose port 8080 of your app in the container and you want to access it from the outside on port 8080 as well, you need to add `-p 8080:8080` to your `docker run` command.